# Problem inserting data into SQL Server via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, ssms

I have a problem with an insert query in PHP.
I'm trying to insert data to SQL Server database.

The query is correctly executed, but the string value are modified.
\0 (null) are inserted between each character.

For example :
GeoFOA is inserted like that \0\0\0G\0\0\0e\0\0\0o\0\0\0F\0\0\0O\0\0\0A

Here's my code : all params had been verified, and they didn't contain any \0

```
$DateTimeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ;

$params = array($IdApp, $Un, $Mn, $Dn, $Mid, $Ip, $DateTimeNow, $ValidLic, $LogMessage);

$sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[LOGS] 
(IDAPPLICATION, USERNAME, MACHINENAME, DOMAINNAME, MACADRESS, PUBLICIP, ACCESSDATE, VALIDLICENCE, COMMENT) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

$rows_affected = sqlsrv_rows_affected( $stmt);
```

There is no errors.
$rows_affected return true.

But when I tried to display result in SSMS with SELECT query field are displayed empty.
If I load the table on edit mode via SSMS, field are not empty, but not editable.

Comment: Have you tried PDO before using sqlsrv_query()? Seems like an issue with the prepared statement i can`t explain.

Comment: No I did'nt try PDO...parameters are all correct when I display them using print...

Comment: I think your sql settings are incorrect, maybe your sql_mode is wrong or your table columns have the wrong type